# is there a better way to read sub process results ? wihtout storing in log file and reading it again

Tags: python-3.x, automation, automated-tests

I have this method where I automate xss attack using XSSsrtike tool (https://github.com/s0md3v/XSStrike/wiki/Usage), is there a better way to validate tool results? currently, I'm doing it based on log file size, if the log file size is 0 the test pass otherwise fails.
this generates a lot of log file when I have sets URLs to test xss attack against.

is there a way to use tool output to validate results? I'm filtering the console output by giving this parameter

```
--console-log-level VULN
```

so the tool prints in the console only when there are vuln results, otherwise prints nothing

```
tooloutput = subprocess.getoutput(command)
                    print("INFO: XSSStrike TOOL FULL RESULTS: " + tooloutput)
```

full method

```
  def run_xss_strike_tool(self, data, tool_path):
        for value in data:
            if not value["ignore"]:
                clean_list = list(set(self.form_urls))
                for url in clean_list:
                    print("INFO : running XSS Injection on paths: " + url)
                    jsonName = datetime.now()
                    jsonNamewithoutSpace = str(jsonName).replace(" ", "")
                    jsonNamewithoutdots = str(jsonNamewithoutSpace).replace(".", "-")
                    formatName = str(jsonNamewithoutdots).replace(":", "-")

                    depth = value["crawl-depth"]
                    if self.cookie == '':
                        command = "cd " + tool_path + " && python xsstrike.py -u " + url + " --params --crawl -l " + depth + " --skip --blind --file-log-level VULN --console-log-level VULN --log-file " + formatName
                    else:
                        cookie_para = f'"cookie:{self.cookie}"'
                        command = "cd " + tool_path + " && python xsstrike.py -u " + url + " --header " + cookie_para + " --params --crawl -l " + depth + " --skip --blind --file-log-level VULN --console-log-level VULN --log-file " + formatName
                        print(command)

                    tooloutput = subprocess.getoutput(command)
                    print("INFO: XSSStrike TOOL FULL RESULTS: " + tooloutput)
                    fullpath = tool_path + formatName
                    filesize = os.stat(fullpath).st_size
                    print(fullpath + " has size of " + str(filesize))

                    if filesize == 0:
                        print('XSS injection check : \' results:\'   \'' "None" '\'' + \
                              ' ... [ ' + self.OKGREEN + 'OK' + self.endColor + ' ]')
                    if filesize > 0:
                        self.nm_of_fails += 1
                        print(
                            'XSS injection check : \' results:\'   \''" found vulnerable pages to xss injection "  '\'' + \
                            ' ... [ ' + self.WARNING + 'WARN' + self.endColor + ' ]')
                        print(tooloutput)
                    # todo remove logfile
            else:
                print("INFO : XSS Injection is skipped!")
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `file` and `console` log levels both set to `VULN` - this means they should both receive the same output.

If you omit the `--log-file` arguments to the `xsstrike` command then it will only log to the console. You are gathering this up in the `tooloutput` variable - and should be able to just look at the length of the variable instead of the file.

Comment: creating a check based on length of toolouput return none :/, any ideal solution to solve this?